# My 2.5 ton HVAC unit

Tags: heating, air-conditioning

We put in a new 2.5 ton Trane HVAC unit, and when it hits 90 outside, it won’t hold 74 degrees inside. (1400-1500 sq. Ft). Will it help to put in a 3 ton unit, or will it do more harm than good?

Comment: There's not a lot of detail here. The key question is *why* won't it hold? Is the blower not putting out enough CFM? Is the unit low on refrigerant? The former would require a new unit, the latter does not.

Comment: Replacing the new 2.5 ton Trane with a 3 ton Trane or other unit of the same capability would allow you to bring the inside temperature to a lower value, but unless you get a special deal from your installer it would cost a lot for marginal improvement. A better approach would be to improve the ceiling insulation. Personally I would not change the a/c, but would try to figure out how to live with it. Where is this 1400 - 1500 sq ft house located? How much ceiling insulation is in place right now?

Comment: How is your house ducted? Throwing more tonnage at an issue with poor HVAC performance is merely a band-aid on a bullet hole...

Comment: Did your previous ac cool better? What size was it? Was any new duct work installed?

Comment: I would suspect poor attic ventilation to remove heat source on the roof

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 or the attic's vented in a hot climate, when it really should be a *conditioned space* under a "hot roof"

Comment: If 2.5 ton unit draws 2300 watts with a very high A+ SEER rating of 6.1 , should it remove 14 kW of heat. If solar heat is 1kW/sq.m.and 1500 sqft absorbs 139kW in the roof max then a net roof insulation of 139 kW/14kW = R10 to maintain roof heat. So I suspect SEER rating is more important than tons and removing attic heat is most important. But if you are in a hot climate , you will want R50 in the roof and triple pane windows. But this does not compute ambient heat power and roof rise to 70’C

Answer (score 1):

With a 1500 sq ft home a 2.5 ton should get it nice and cool. 
Things that may affect your ability to cool, ducting not insulated, home not insulated, extreme heat (I don’t consider 90 extreme)

You did not state what the unit did cool to. Without this we cannot calculate the delta to tell if a larger unit would work for your home. 
The tonnage of a unit is how much it will cool the Seer is the efficiency higher seer less monthly electricity demands.

I have installed larger evaporators in the past when I knew the owner was going too small. The evaporators can handle a range of cooling where the compressor and condenser are usually 1 unit (the outside unit).

I would check with your installer is this unit have a dual speed or variable speed fan that is not being turned on? I have seen ac units air handlers on low speed and they did not cool as well. For a friend I installed a new controller and my friend thought I put a new system in it worked so much better (~150$ took care of him)

So there are possibly things that could improve the performance of your existing system insulation and possibly different fan speeds both of these would be much cheaper than a new compressor / condenser and possibly a evaporator if yours is not large enough to handle a bigger compressor.